# How to update an Adsets (nested) targeting options via the Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: node.js, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to update an existing Adsets targeting options, but I just want the `publisher_platforms` to be changed. The error message I get is the following:

```
  error_user_msg: 'Your audience is missing a location. You can add a location or a Custom Audience.',
```

This error shows me that I'm using the wrong endpoint, since I just want update one targeting field not the entire options.

Here is my call to the api

```js
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/${adSetId}`,
    qs: {
      access_token: accessToken,
      "targeting": {publisher_platforms: ["instagram"]}
    }
};

request(options, (err, data, body) => {

   console.log("updateFacebookCampaign", "then..." ,{
     body
   });
})
```

Any idea how I can archive this? (incrementally updating the targeting options and not all at once)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update a single value of the `targeting` field the way you are attempting to.

When updating the adset targeting you need to pass the entire `targeting` object, of which `geo_locations` is a required field. The `targeting` field will be replaced by the new object you send in the update.

To successfully update the targeting, pass the new targeting object as it would be with your updated `publisher_platforms`.